# join and append List into string in Python with several condition

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, nltk

I need help from my case

I have 2 lists in Python that contain word and the tagging:

```
[['The', 'DT'], ['Kawasaki', 'NNP'], ['Ki-100', 'NNP'], ['fighter', 'NN']...
```

and another list that contains word and the NER tag:

```
[['Kawasaki', 'ORGANIZATION'], ['Imperial', 'ORGANIZATION'], ['Army Air Service', 'ORGANIZATION'], ['Japanese', 'GPE'] ...
```

I want to join the first list and the second list so it will show like this string:

```
'Kawasaki NNP ORGANIZATION'
```

And all words at the first list must have format like that , and if there's no NER tag for the word , it must be show like this:

```
'Kawasaki NNP'
```

and change it into dictionary like this:

```
{'Kawasaki NNP ORGANIZATION',0}
```

But when I try to make it , there's word that should has NER-Tag , the tag not showed at the list.

This is the code for take the first list:

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize

def taggering(text):
tagger = []
tag = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(text))
for w in range(len(tag)):
    temp = list(tag[w])
    tagger.append(temp)
print(tagger)
return tagger
```

This is the code for take the first list:

```
def NER_ring(text):
datasets = []

for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text):
    for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
        if hasattr(chunk, 'label'):
            temp = [' '.join(c[0] for c in chunk), chunk.label()]
            datasets.append(temp)
print(datasets)
return datasets
```

This is the lines that I try to make the target text and dictionary:

```
def builder(datasets,tagger):
ls = {}
new_build = []
temp=[]
for i in range(len(tagger)):
    words = str( tagger[i][0])
    tags = str(tagger[i][1])
    listed = [words,tags]
    temp.append(listed)
for w in range (len(temp)):
    for k in range (len(datasets)):
        if(temp[w][0]==datasets[k][0]):
            classtype = str(datasets[k][1])
        else:
            classtype = ""
        k++1
    word2 = temp[w][0]
    tag2 = temp[w][1]
    listed = str(word2+" "+tag2+" "+classtype)
    ls[listed]=0
    new_build.append(ls)
    w++1
return new_build
```

I need some wise advice to finish this code , so I can use the list for IR calculation. Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by 'if no NER tag, then change it into dictionary like this:'

Comment: If there's a NER tag (PERSON , ORGANIZATION , etc) , the format will be like this ['Kawasaki NNP PERSON']. If there's no matching NER tag  ,in any vocabulary cases , it will be like this ['run VB ']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
l1 = [['The', 'DT'], ['Kawasaki', 'NNP'], ['Ki-100', 'NNP'], ['fighter', 'NN']]
l2=[['Kawasaki', 'ORGANIZATION'], ['Imperial', 'ORGANIZATION'], ['Army Air Service', 'ORGANIZATION'], ['Japanese', 'GPE']]
d={}  # Output dict
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        if i[0] == j[0]:
           d['{} {} {}'.format(i[0], i[1], j[1])] = 0  # Desired number if match
           break
        d['{} {}'.format(i[0], i[1])] = 0  # Desired number if not match
```

the `d` will be

```
{
 'Kawasaki NNP ORGANIZATION': 0,
 'Ki-100 NNP': 0, 'The DT': 0,
 'fighter NN': 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you . The new modification for the code works , and i will do some modification again , so all punctuation , except . and - will be not include in TF-IDF calculation